# Define new properties of a class in phpDoc after dynamically add new property to the class

Tags: php, phpdoc

for an example I have an Eloquent modal named 'Student'

```
$student = Student::first();
```

we can add PHP doc comment to this variable like this.

```
/**
* @var Student $student
*/
$student = Student::first();
```

in Eloquent modals we can set new attributes at the runtime

```
$student->setAttribute('is_a_good_boy', true);
```

now, is there a way to add this dynamic property to the phpDOc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`@property`](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) tag for this purpose. For example:

```
/**
 * @property boolean $is_a_good_boy
 */
class Student {

}
```

Comment: that property is not always in the class.
only after that function is called.

Comment: PHPDoc by its nature is static definition, not dynamic. Your question was about a way to define "magically" defined properties in PHPDoc, `@property` tag is for this purpose. PHPDoc just defines metadata for PHP code, it have no knowledge about runtime.

Comment: i guess you are right. there is no way to archive my goal.   the only reason i was looking for a way to do so is, my IDE helps me with code completion and suggestions using the doc comments.

Comment: Yes, that's why we're normally defining these PHPDoc blocks. It is ok to have these `@property` to be defined to help IDE to know your code better and you can leave additional comments for the humans so they will know that some particular properties are not permanently defined.